# ROS2 rolling header location for different Ubuntu version

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two clean installed Ubuntu, 20.04 and 22.04, and both of them are installed with ROS2 rolling.
Somehow I found their std_msgs headers are located in different folders as shown [image: here].

The Ubuntu 22.04 has one more extra include layer for the std_msgs. Is this the expected behavior for different Ubuntu versions?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412383/ros2-rolling-header-location-for-different-ubuntu-version/) by [Chris7462](https://answers.ros.org/users/59813/chris7462/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I found their std_msgs headers are located in different folders as shown here.
>
> The Ubuntu 22.04 has one more extra include layer for the std_msgs. Is this the expected behavior for different Ubuntu versions?

I wouldn't call it *behaviour*, but: yes, this is expected. See [ros2/ros2#1150](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1150) for context.

Note: unless you're (planning to) manually manage your include paths, this change should not have any affect on your development workflow. CMake will take care of sorting things out for you.

> I have two clean installed Ubuntu, 20.04 and 22.04, and both of them are installed with ROS2 rolling.

please note: Rolling on Focal (`20.04`) is no longer being updated. It saw its last *sync* on 2022-01-28, which is over a year ago. See the following discussions for context:

- [Preparing ROS 2 Rolling for the transition to Ubuntu 22.04](https://discourse.ros.org/t/preparing-ros-2-rolling-for-the-transition-to-ubuntu-22-04/23124)
- [Preparing for final Rolling sync on Ubuntu Focal 2022-01-25](https://discourse.ros.org/t/preparing-for-final-rolling-sync-on-ubuntu-focal-2022-01-25/23920)
- [Rolling Ridley has rolled onto Ubuntu Jammy](https://discourse.ros.org/t/rolling-ridley-has-rolled-onto-ubuntu-jammy/24400)
- [New packages for ROS 2 Rolling Ridley 2022-01-28](https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-packages-for-ros-2-rolling-ridley-2022-01-28/24067)

Basically: Rolling on Focal is very different from Rolling on Jammy.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chris7462](https://answers.ros.org/users/59813/chris7462/) on 2023-02-15**:
I see. Thank you for your reply. Really appreciate it.